# Online course for learning Vim editor

Tags: 16.10, vim

I want to learn the `Vim` editor. Could anyone recommend a good course on the web? In fact, I'd like something interactive where we could do some examples.

**P.S.** It would be good if you could explain why it is a good course and whether you learn with this course.

Comment: try the vim installed tutorial by running this in the terminal `vimtutor`

Comment: [vim.se] is a good place to start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you like gaming, you might enjoy [Vim Adventures](http://vim-adventures.com/)

Only the first level is free to play I think, but even that is excellent for learning some basic things like cursor movement. It was helpful for me because it forces you to use the most efficient commands and thus get used to them, rather than cheating with arrow keys and so on.

Of course, you are welcome to ask questions about using Vim on Ubuntu here (or on [Vi & Vim SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)), but questions about Vim Adventures itself are off topic and should instead be asked on [Gaming SE with the appropriate tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-adventures). The solutions for the game can be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/pepers/vim-adventures) (Many thanks to @Rinzwind for those two links)

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the "Vim" this Vim : http://www.vim.org/

There are a lot of tutorials on youtube but i would recommend this one : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SI8TeVMX8pk

I hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

If you would accept 'already locally installed software' as 'online', go ahead and use `vimtutor` (or `gvimtutor` for the gvim version), which already installed with your vim-runtime and gives a good introduction.